# Alternative XCode documentation readers

Tags: xcode, documentation

The XCode developer documentation manager is pretty good on the whole (search is speedy, formatting is good, organization is pretty good, etc), but there are a couple of things that I feel are missing including (or may just have missed):

1. Fuzzier search: after typing "UITabelViwCell" a bunch of times, it would be nice to get some suggestions.
2. Ability to view multiple docs (tabbing or multiple windows).
3. History/frequency-aware suggestions (maybe project-aware too).
4. Some links are missing. I can't remember exactly where, but I seem to think it's around typedefs or enums or other less object-oriented places.
5. Back-button support can be flaky sometimes.

So is there any kind of documentation tool that provides these kinds of features or am I somehow wrong for wanting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, have a look at

http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads/appkido.html

maybe that suits all your needs.

The issues you list could also be solved by just using your normal internet browser. If you have a decent internet connection it is not really loading any slower than the XCode documentation (I don't know what they do with the window, but when searching for something it takes really long and reformats everything a few times), and provides you with 1 (fuzzy search, google.com/cse), 2 (tabbing), 3 (history) and 5 (back-button); 4 should be just another quick 1.